# Referencing nested arrays in awk

Tags: awk

I'm creating a bunch of mappings that can be indexed into using 3 keys such as below:

```
mappings["foo"]["bar"]["blah"][1]=0
split( "10,13,19,49", mappings["foo"]["bar"]["blah"] )
```

I can then index into the nested array using for example

```
mappings[product][format][version][i]
```

But this is a bit long-winded when I need to refer to the same nested array several times, so in other languages I'd create a reference to the inner array:

```
map=mappings[product][format][version]
map[i]
```

However, I can't seem to get this to work in awk (gawk 4.1.3).

I can only find one link over google, that suggests this is impossible in previous versions of awk, and a loop setting the keys and values one-by-one is the only solution.  Is this still the case or does anyone have a suggestions for a better solution?

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/OpenSource/Conceptual/ShellScripting/Howawk-ward/Howawk-ward.html

**EDIT**

In response to comments a bit more background on what I'm trying to do.  If there is a better approach, I'm all for using it!

I have set of CSV files that I'm feeding into AWK.  The idea is to calculate a checksum based on specific columns after applying filtering to the rows.

The columns to checksum on, and the filtering to apply, are derivived from runtime parameters sent into the script.

The runtime parameters are a triple of (product,format,version), hence my use of a 3-nested assoicative array.

Another approach would be to use triple as a single key, rather than nesting, but gawk doesn't seem to natively support this, so I'd end-up concatenating the values as string.  This felt a bit less structured to me, but if I'm wrong, happy to change my mind on this apporach.

Anyway, it is these parameters that are used to index into the array to structure to retrieve the column numbers, etc.

You can then build-up a tree-like structure, for example, the below shows 2 formats for product foo on version blah, and so on...:

```
mappings["product-foo"]["format-bar"]["version-blah"][1]=0
split( "10,13,19,49", mappings["product-foo"]["format-bar"]["version-blah"] )
mappings["product-foo"]["format-moo"]["version-blah"][1]=0
split( "55,23,14,6", mappings["product-foo"]["format-moo"]["version-blah"] )
```

The magic happens like this, you can see how long-winded the mappings indexing becomes without referencing:

```
    (FNR>1 && (format!="some-format" ||
              (version=="some-version" && $1=="some-filter")  ||
              (version=="some-other-version" && $8=="some-other-filter"))) {
           # Loop over each supplied field summing an absolute tally for each
           for (i=1; i <= length(mappings[product][format][version]); i++) {
               sumarr[i] += ( $mappings[product][format][version][i] < 0 ? -$mappings[product][format][version][i]:$mappings[product][format][version][i] )
           }
    }
```

The comment from @ed-morton simplifies this as originally requested, but interested if their is a simpler approach.

Comment: What is the problem that you are tying to solve here? Start with posting a minimal example of your input and explain how your output should look like? I'm sure there are far easy ways to solve this

Comment: Right, there is no array copy functionality in awk and there are no pointers/references so you can't create a pointer to an array. You can of course create `function map(i) { return mappings[product][format][version][i]}`.

Comment: You might be interested to introduce the abs function in awk. This will reduce the lookup time of your mappings as you only need to do it a single time. `function abs(x) { return x<0 ? -x : x }` and call it with `sumarr[i] += abs($mappings[product][format][version][i])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right answer is from @ed-morton above (thanks!).

Ed - if you write it out as an answer I'll accept it, otherwise I'll accept this quote in a few days for good housekeeping.

> Right, there is no array copy functionality in awk and there are no pointers/references so you can't create a pointer to an array. You can of course create function map(i) { return mappings[product][format][version][i]}